# Data Table Column Merge for Pre-Post Data

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like this:

```
   ID age gender relationship   ACESscore PAPre PAPost NAPre NAPost PADelta NADelta
   3 6192  32      2            2         2     8     10    NA      3       2      NA
   4 6191  31      1            1         0     8     10     4      2       2      -2
   6 8421  25      1            2         0     9      9     3      5       0       2
   7 9991  18      1           NA        10     7      9     2      3       2       1
   8 9992  18      2           NA         5     8      8     4      2       0      -2
   9 7612  35      2            1         1     4      7     5      3       3      -2
```

I want to make a line graph of PA/Pre-Post and NA/Pre-Post and I think the best way to do that (correct me if I'm wrong) is to get a new table that looks like:

```
 ID age gender relationship   ACESscore  PA         NA    PREPOST
   3 6192  32      2            2         2         10        1
   4 6191  31      1            1         0         10        1
   6 8421  25      1            2         0          9        1
   7 9991  18      1           NA        10          9        1
   8 9992  18      2           NA         5          8        1
   9 7612  35      2            1         1          7        1
   10 6192  32      2            2        8         NA        2
   11 6191  31      1            1        8         4         2
   12 8421  25      1            2        9          3        2
   13 9991  18      1           NA        7          2        2
   14 9992  18      2           NA        8          4        2
   15 7612  35      2            1        4          5        2
```

How do I make it so that there is now two lines for ever ID and PAPre is stacked with PAPost, and the same for the two NAPre/Post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a reshape long via `melt`.

```
melt(dat[, -c("PADelta", "NADelta")],
     measure.vars=list(c("PAPre", "PAPost"), c("NAPre", "NAPost")),
     value.name=c("PAVal", "NAVal"), variable.name="prepost")
```

`dat[, -c("PADelta", "NADelta")]` drops the delta variables. The variables to be folded down are put into a list in the measure.vars argument. The final two arguments provide names for the newly created variables.

This returns

```
      ID age gender relationship ACESscore prepost PAVal NAVal
 1: 6192  32      2            2         2       1     8    NA
 2: 6191  31      1            1         0       1     8     4
 3: 8421  25      1            2         0       1     9     3
 4: 9991  18      1           NA        10       1     7     2
 5: 9992  18      2           NA         5       1     8     4
 6: 7612  35      2            1         1       1     4     5
 7: 6192  32      2            2         2       2    10     3
 8: 6191  31      1            1         0       2    10     2
 9: 8421  25      1            2         0       2     9     5
10: 9991  18      1           NA        10       2     9     3
11: 9992  18      2           NA         5       2     8     2
12: 7612  35      2            1         1       2     7     3
```

Note: The initial post used `dat[, .SD, .SDcols=-c("PADelta", "NADelta")]` to to subset the variables. In a comment, Frank alerted me that this can be done much more concisely with `dat[, -c("PADelta", "NADelta")]`.

Frank also noted that the data.table `patterns` function can be used to find variable names matching certain patterns for matching up on the variable names to be folded down. Here is a more concise and extensible (imagine more than 2 periods) method using this function.

```
melt(dat[, -c("PADelta", "NADelta")],
     measure.vars=patterns("^PA", "^NA"),
     value.name=c("PAVal", "NAVal"), variable.name="prepost")
```

**Data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(ID = c(6192L, 6191L, 8421L, 9991L, 9992L, 7612L
), age = c(32L, 31L, 25L, 18L, 18L, 35L), gender = c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), relationship = c(2L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L), ACESscore = c(2L, 
0L, 0L, 10L, 5L, 1L), PAPre = c(8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 4L), PAPost = c(10L, 
10L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 7L), NAPre = c(NA, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), NAPost = c(3L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L), PADelta = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L), NADelta = c(NA, 
-2L, 2L, 1L, -2L, -2L)), .Names = c("ID", "age", "gender", "relationship", 
"ACESscore", "PAPre", "PAPost", "NAPre", "NAPost", "PADelta", 
"NADelta"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `dat[, -c("PADelta", "NADelta")]` should work on current CRAN version, I think (instead of `.SD` shenanigans). Also fyi, you have the option of using `patterns()` in `measure.vars`.

Comment: When I run the code, I get `Error in -c("PADelta", "NADelta") : invalid argument to unary operator`. If I run it without that bit, I get `Error: measure variables not found in data: c("PAPre", "PAPost"), c("NAPre", "NAPost")
`

Comment: @HeatherCohen This method works with the data you provided (copy and paste my data section) using `data.table` 1.10.4. It is possible that you don't have the most recent version of `data.table`, or that you need to convert your data.frame to a data.table using `setDT`.